# Indexing service

Tags: indexing, indexing-service

I have a problem to get data by Indexing Service.

> ServerName: **RETSO-NT21.CA.com**
>     CatalogName: **MyCatalog1**
>     TextSearch: **test**

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT path, filename 
FROM RETSO-NT21.CA.com.MyCatalog1..scope() 
WHERE FREETEXT(Contents,'%test%')
```

When I run it I'll get this error message:

> Incorrect syntax near '-'.  Expected end-of-file, ';', AS, CREATE,
>   DOT, DOTDOT, DOTDOT_SCOPE, DOTDOTDOT, DOTDOTDOT_SCOPE, DROP, ORDER_BY,
>   SELECT, SET, WHERE. SQLSTATE=42000

It's working fine when I use a server name without "-" & "."
But obviously I can not change server name.

Anybody can help how can I use server name with special characters in query??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution. 
Just needs to put the server name in " ". 
like this:

```
SELECT path, filename 
FROM "RETSO-NT21.CA.com".MyCatalog1..scope() 
WHERE FREETEXT(Contents,'%test%')
```